# Unexpected behavior in data.table join when using nomatch and allow.cartesian

Tags: r, data.table

I have 2 data tables and am trying to get a column cor from cortable into finaltable.

cortable

```
cor,tickerkey
0.7539,AAL_AAN
0.573,AAL_ABB
0.6384,AAL_ACM
0.7193,AAL_ACXM
0.8386,AAL_ADP
0.7392,AAL_ADT
0.732,AAL_AER
0.4805,AAL_AGCO
0.9363,AAL_AL
0.9064,AAL_ALK
0.7545,AAL_ALSN
0.8586,AAL_AME
0.3356,AAL_AMT
0.8239,AAL_AN
0.8637,AAL_AOS
0.7638,AAL_APD
0.7915,AAL_APH
0.8785,AAL_APOL
0.8073,AAL_ARMH
0.7744,AAL_ASH
0.4179,AAL_ATLS
0.8282,AAL_AWI
-0.2539,AAL_AWK
0.8213,AAL_AXLL
0.827,AAL_BA
0.8642,AAL_BC
0.7982,AAL_BCO
0.2002,AAL_BEAV
0.7079,AAL_BERY
0.858,AAL_BGC
0.5943,AAL_BRK.B
0.1522,AAL_BWC
0.2793,AAL_CAR
0.8537,AAL_CAT
0.9115,AAL_CBI
```

dput

```
cortable<-structure(list(cor = c("0.7539", "0.573", "0.6384", "0.7193", 
                                  "0.8386", "0.7392", "0.732", "0.4805", "0.9363", "0.9064", "0.7545", 
                                  "0.8586", "0.3356", "0.8239", "0.8637", "0.7638", "0.7915", "0.8785", 
                                  "0.8073", "0.7744", "0.4179", "0.8282", "-0.2539", "0.8213", 
                                  "0.827", "0.8642", "0.7982", "0.2002", "0.7079", "0.858", "0.5943", 
                                  "0.1522", "0.2793", "0.8537", "0.9115"), 
                          tickerkey = c("AAL_AAN", "AAL_ABB", "AAL_ACM", "AAL_ACXM", "AAL_ADP", "AAL_ADT", "AAL_AER", 
                                                                                         "AAL_AGCO", "AAL_AL", "AAL_ALK", "AAL_ALSN", "AAL_AME", "AAL_AMT", 
                                                                                         "AAL_AN", "AAL_AOS", "AAL_APD", "AAL_APH", "AAL_APOL", "AAL_ARMH", 
                                                                                         "AAL_ASH", "AAL_ATLS", "AAL_AWI", "AAL_AWK", "AAL_AXLL", "AAL_BA", 
                                                                                         "AAL_BC", "AAL_BCO", "AAL_BEAV", "AAL_BERY", "AAL_BGC", "AAL_BRK.B", 
                                                                                         "AAL_BWC", "AAL_CAR", "AAL_CAT", "AAL_CBI")), .Names = c("cor", 
                                                                                                                                                  "tickerkey"), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "data.frame"), sorted = "tickerkey")
```

finaltable

```
tickerkey,ticker1,ticker2
AAL_ALK,AAL,ALK
AAL_CAR,AAL,CAR
AAL_CHRW,AAL,CHRW
AAL_CNW,AAL,CNW
AAL_CSX,AAL,CSX
AAL_DAL,AAL,DAL
AAL_EXPD,AAL,EXPD
AAL_FDX,AAL,FDX
AAL_HTZ,AAL,HTZ
AAL_JBHT,AAL,JBHT
```

dput

```
    finaltable<-structure(list(tickerkey = c("AAL_ALK", "AAL_CAR", "AAL_CHRW", 
                                             "AAL_CNW", "AAL_CSX", "AAL_DAL", "AAL_EXPD", "AAL_FDX", "AAL_HTZ", 
                                             "AAL_JBHT"), ticker1 = c("AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", 
                                                                      "AAL", "AAL", "AAL", "AAL"), ticker2 = c("ALK", "CAR", "CHRW", 
                                                                                                               "CNW", "CSX", "DAL", "EXPD", "FDX", "HTZ", "JBHT")), .Names = c("tickerkey", 
                                                                                                                                                                               "ticker1", "ticker2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "data.frame"), sorted = "tickerkey")
```

I am trying to achieve that with the code as below.

`setkey(cortable, "tickerkey")`
`setkey(finaltable, "tickerkey")`

`finaltable[cortable,cor:=cor,allow.cartesian=TRUE,nomatch=0]`

The correct expected output would be finaltable

```
tickerkey,ticker1,ticker2,cor
AAL_ALK,AAL,ALK,0.9064
AAL_CAR,AAL,CAR,0.2793
```

with the rest of the rows having value of NA for cor

but it gives an output

finaltable

```
tickerkey,ticker1,ticker2,cor
AAL_ALK,AAL,ALK,0.2793
AAL_CAR,AAL,CAR,0.9064
```

with the rest of the rows NA for cor. and a warning on execution.. `In [.data.table(finaltable, cortable, :=(cor, cor), allow.cartesian = TRUE, : Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 35 items of column 'cor' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).`

If I remove nomatch argument, the mismatch doesn't happen.
I am trying to find out exactly whats causing this behavior, as I have a lot of code/data analysis that uses this and without knowing the exact cause of a probable unexpected behavior, brings down my confidence in all the data generated so far.

I tried to look into the definition/behaviour of nomatch, didn't find much in the context of the above usage. If anyone could give some explanation, will be very helpful.

Comment: Downvoting because I don't like the expectation that we read in csv data. Here's a reference for how to provide example data http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/1191259 Or just look at other questions in the R tag...

Comment: @Frank unless I'm misinterpreting the question, you shouldn't need the data.  It appears they just need proper merge syntax.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor: It is always good to test with the sample data before posting an answer.

Comment: @user227710 I mean that is certainly preferable to no data and especially for complex cases but, in this particular case, it appears the answer is simple enough as to make testing unnecessary.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor: You are right , but if you run your code, you will see that your answer doesn't match with the expected output.

Comment: @user227710 what isn't matching?  the column order?  I'm assuming their "expected output" has just taken a subset of the rows and that they do want all the rows.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor: Please test your code and see whether it matches with the expected output.

Comment: I am retrieving the column as above, not doing a merge, because the original data set is much bigger, and a merge would be more computationally intensive. The mismatch part, the cor value is being assigned to the wrong row. If you look at AAL_ALK, the cor value in the original table is 0.9064, but its giving .2793. I tested this with the data, brought down the data to as minimal as possible so I could post here. I will try to get more acquainted with posting guidelines.

Comment: @user2956863: You are supposed to show the expected output for your "sample data", not the original data and also please `dput` the sample data for reproducibility.

Comment: Hi, I showed  the expected output and the observed output, below my sample code. I am not trying to find another way to achieve this. I know other ways to. I have a lot of existing code that uses nomatch and that generated a lot of data. Unless I know whats causing this issue I have to regenerate all that data by substituting all the instances utilizing nomatch argument, which would take considerable time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do think that there was a genuine behaviour observed contrary to expectations, and I tested it out well before posting. I hope a bit of inexperience in posting shouldn't make people downright the question and increase the chance the question go unanswered. Will definitely try  to be more formatted in my posts.

Comment: :                ` tickerkey ticker1 ticker2    cor
 1:                 AAL_CAR     AAL     CAR     NA
 2:                AAL_CHRW     AAL    CHRW     NA
 3:                 AAL_CNW     AAL     CNW     NA
 4:                 AAL_CSX     AAL     CSX     NA
 5:                 AAL_DAL     AAL     DAL     NA
 6:                AAL_EXPD     AAL    EXPD     NA
 7:                 AAL_FDX     AAL     FDX     NA
 8:                 AAL_HTZ     AAL     HTZ     NA
 9:                AAL_JBHT     AAL    JBHT     NA
10:                 AAL_ALK     AAL     ALK 0.9064`.

Comment: That is the output I got from your code. I am using development version 1.9.5+

Comment: Hi user227710, Thanks for taking the time to test out my issue. If you look at AAL_CAR it has a value of NA in your output, but 0.2793 in the original cortable, which is a different type of mismatch observed. The version I used was 1.9.4. and the output I had switched the 2 values 0.9064 and 0.2793 between AAL_ALK and AAL_CAR. Is my usage incorrect, conceptually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
merge(cortable, finaltable, by=c('tickerkey'))[,list(tickerkey,ticker1,ticker2,cor)]
```

or you could do

```
cortable[finaltable][!is.na(cor)][,list(tickerkey,ticker1,ticker2,cor)]
```

the latter approach assumes you've set keys whereas the first doesn't matter if the keys are set.

Comment: Hi Dean, I am trying to find the bug in the usage I listed above, and what triggers that perceived bug or behavior. Because I have existing data that was generated using that code, I am trying to decide if I should regenerate the data, coz if mismatches like the above happened the data I have is incorrect. Since it takes a significant time to regenerate, I am bothering people to find out what exactly causes this bug/behavior so I can minimize the regeneration to those  specific cases which encounter data which triggers that perceived bug.

Comment: @user2956863  I think I see what your problem is.  I don't think setting new columns and `nomatch` was intended to be used simultaneously which is why you're getting the error about 35 vs 2 fields.  `nomatch` correctly limits the results to 2 entries but finaltable[cortable] wants there to be 35.  If you take a row out of `cortable` and do this again then you won't get the error because 2 is divisible into 34 and it just repeats the assignment over and over which is why they appear to offset.

Comment: Hi Dean, Thanks so much for your time. That sheds light a bit in the direction I was looking for. So, I guess It was incorrect usage. I tested for the divisibility thing though after you mentioned, once rows(cortable) > rows(finaltable) and after it hits the issue while I keep increasing the numrows of cortable, the issue stays. Not sure if I can make sense of observations from an incorrect usage...Thanks again.

Comment: @user2956863 I don't think you can safely use any observations this way.  By the way, would you mind accepting the answer?